# SPRINGBOOT - Auto resolve which dependency to inject Globally

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I usually like to do(I do this in JS/TS) the injection based on a Interface,and "register a token" pointing to a default Implementation.So If I someday need to create a new Implementation I don't need to change the whole code, I only need to change that Token to another implementation.

I was trying to do the same in Spring. However I'm still learning about its IOC and DI, and I could not find something like this.

So my question is, in my controller when I'm injecting the Interface, I need to use a "**@Qualifier**", or specify which one is a **"@Primary"** in my implementation so the **@Autowired** can Inject the correct implementation. The strategy with **@Qualifier()** is good because it allows me to specify it by name, but I still would need to change in the Whole project if someday the implementation needs to be changed.

But I was wondering if there's some way to globally define a configuration pointing to a default injection point to a single implementation?

Thanks in advance. Sorry if my explanation is not clear,please let me know

**Controller Method**

```
@Autowired
private IOrdinaryService iOrdinaryService;

@GetMapping("/")
void getMethodHangler() {
    iCreateProjectService.execute(newEmployee);
}
```

**Interface**

```
package com.example.demo.modules.projects.services;
import com.example.demo.modules.projects.entities.Projects;

public interface IOrdinaryService{
    void execute();
}
```

**Implementation 1**

```
@Service
public class OldWayOrdinaryService implements IOrdinaryService {
    
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("foo");

    }
}
```

**Implementation 2**

```
@Service
public class NewWayOrdinaryService implements IOrdinaryService {
    
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("bar");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with configuration classes of `Spring` framework:

```
@Configuration
public class InjectionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public IOrdinaryService ordinaryService() {
        return new OldWayOrdinaryService();
    }
}
```

This way, you don't need to use `@Service` annotation on the implementations, so remove it, and you will get the instance you need in your controller class with @Autowired.

When you want to change the implementation of a `IOrdinaryService`, you just change the above configuration method.

Comment: Wow thanks! This works great! It is exactly what I was looking for! Just One question, does it create a singleton? Or each call it creates a new instance?

Comment: Here Spring uses the default scope, so for each call Spring will create a new instance. Of course, you can change the scope using @Scope("singleton") with @Bean.

Answer (score 0):

You can externalize implementation class name as a system property that you can use in configuration method to inject or autowire.